# What does the Key reference in MySQL sdi_delete failed message?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run this query on a MySQL database:

`alter table table_name alter column_name set default 6160`

The console tells me:

> Failed to delete sdi for database_name.table_name in
> database_name/table_name due to missing record.

The MySQL `error.log` file tells me:

> [InnoDB] sdi_delete failed: Record Doesn't exist: tablespace_id: 111111 Key: 1 222222

Note that the ID of 111111 and Key 222222 here are made up. There is a 1 after "Key:" and before 222222 though.

So I figured out I can find out the table it's referring to, using this query:

`select * from information_schema.INNODB_TABLESPACES_BRIEF where space = 111111`

And sure enough, the result gives me `database_name/table_name` as the first error message says.

But there are no constraints on this table other than the primary key. And there are not 6-figures worth of rows in it, so the key it's printing out can't refer to a value in the `id` column in my table.

What is Key: 1 222222 referring to? How can I find out which specific record it's referring to?

Comment: bugs.mysql.com -- consider filing a bug report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDI key is not referring to anything in your table; it's the key of the [Serialized Dictionary Information](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/serialized-dictionary-information.html) record for the table itself. SDI is new for MySQL 8, so if your table(space) was created by an earlier version, the record would not exist (and would probably be created after a successful DDL statement against the table).

If it existed, you would be able to use the [`ibd2sdi` utility](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/ibd2sdi.html) to retrieve the table information by passing it the `--type` (1) and `--id` (222222) of the record.

---

The meaning of fields in the warning message can be gleaned from the [source code](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/6846e6b2f72931991cc9fd589dc9946ea2ab58c9/storage/innobase/api/api0api.cc#L3167):

```cpp
      ib::warn(ER_IB_MSG_11) << "sdi_delete failed: Record Doesn't exist:"
                             << " tablespace_id: " << tablespace_id
                             << " Key: " << ib_sdi_key->sdi_key->type << " "
                             << ib_sdi_key->sdi_key->id;
      // Emit warning, and report missing record error, but do not
      // assert since this situation can occur when upgrading from a
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you!  You mention it would "would probably be created after a successful DDL statement against the table" but since I am doing a DDL statement here and it's erroring out on me, is there something I can do to fix it so that the statement will run?

Comment: `check table table_name for upgrade` worked for me

Answer (score 0):

@mustaccio answered the question as I presented it, but if you are finding this question and wondering what to do to fix the issue so your DDL statement can run, what worked for me is:

`check table table_name for upgrade`

After I ran that, I was able to successfully run my DDL statement.